How to get metadata from .mnc files?
When I convert my DICOMS do nifti, I get a json file, where I can see all the metadata (scan details etc.). However no such files are produced when converting to .mnc. Is there a way to get these? or do I just need to go back to my DICOMS, convert them to .nii also, and look in the .json file?
